# Type of Regex in Eclipse MAT

Tags: java, eclipse, memory, heap-memory, analysis

What type of Regex syntax does MAT support? I assumed it would be Java's (though Java's Regex isnt Regular per se) but it didn't seem to work.. I tried Perl's and it didn't work. I need Regex's to filter out the list in MAT's Histogram. eg:
Include arrays but exclude char arrays.
Exclude java.lang.String
Include java.util.Collections.*

For arrays just typing in "[]" (without quotes) works and I could manually type each one in but I'd like to do it in one go to automate the process.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Regex that you can use to include and exclude multiple Strings in the Eclipse MAT histogram filter.

## Regex filter to include Strings

> `.*STRING1.*|.*STRING2.*|.*STRING3.*`

Example include "java.util", "java.lang", "char[]"

> `.*java.util.*|.*java.lang.*|.*char\[\].*`

## Regex filter to exclude Strings

> `^(?!.*STRING1|.*STRING2|.*STRING3).*$`

Example exclude "java.util", "java.lang", "char[]"

> `^(?!.*java.util|.*java.lang|.*char\[\]).*$`